# Can't launch specific Activity from notification using Firebase

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-notifications

I try to launch activity from notification which is updated when new user added to database(i'm using firebase database).

Notification works perfectly but whenever i'm trying to launch  UserDashboardActivity from notification. it's not working.

can anyone help me.

**My code:**

Here notification code inside Service

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        notifyMe(order.amount);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void notifyMe(String amount){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.add_order)
            .setContentTitle("New Order")
            .setContentText("Order amount: " + amount)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,UserDashboardActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
    }
}
```

I am starting the Service when UserDoashboardActivity is stopped

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Intent intent = new Intent(UserDashboardActivity.this, NotificationService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Comment: Just to make it clear - if you replace just UserDashboardActivity with any other activity, it works?

Comment: Yeah exactly...

Comment: Also I am starting the service from UserDashboardActivity

Comment: Maybe there is some screwing up or leaking because you are sending UDActivity's reference as context. In activity, try sending app context instead of activity.

Alternatively, put some other activity in the service, instead of UDActivity, and edit onStop() method in that oder activity to start service as the onStop() method in UDActivity, and see what's happening

Comment: Also, if your service is started automatically when change in DB occurs, why would you start the service manually as well? This doesn't seem well written.

Comment: Are you serious, how can a service can start automatically ??

Comment: Also I passed Application context to instead of UDActivity did not work

Comment: Thanks by the way I found solution myself

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in notifyMe() function...

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityName.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```